# [NSCFArray replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: mutating method sent to immutable object

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, ios8.1

**UPDATED**  This is my code; the last line of code caused the error as described in the title.  I understand userDefaults will always return an immutable object; so how do I fix this? I tried making the sending field a "mutable copy" but it was flagged as an error.

```
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

   if(textField.tag == kStaffName)  {  //  get index of staffName textField
    NSMutableArray *staffNamesArray = [[userDefaults arrayForKey:@"staffNamesArray"] mutableCopy];

    NSInteger indexSelected = [oStaffPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];

    [staffNamesArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexSelected withObject:textField.text];
```

Comment: @njzk2 Definitely not a duplicate: the code already uses `mutableCopy` and, thus, matches [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5710719/11940).

Comment: Since there is an "if" cleverly hidden beyond the right border of the screen, are you sure you are not modifying any other arrays that are still immutable?

Comment: `it was flagged as an error`. please clarify?

Comment: Question updated - sorry I didn't see the "cleverly hidden if statement"... it's fixed now.

Comment: Error is  the title of the question...

Comment: @njzk2: how about removing the downvote, if indeed it's your doing?  Thanks...

Comment: @njzk2: error was "bad receiver type" (mutableCopy was placed at end of statement)

Comment: You can try this:
NSMutableArray *staffNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[userDefaults arrayForKey:@"staffNamesArray"] mutableCopy]];

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace. Have you added a breakpoint to verify the crash location and the array class?

Comment: @spokane-dude: how about not assuming things, and adding the complete error log to your question?

Comment: @njzk2: Sorry about forgetting the stack trace... I uploaded it to pastBin... 
http://pastebin.com/40c5Sxc4

Comment: @Wain:  can't reproduce it...

Comment: @weso: that looks good... I'll update my code and see if I can cause it to crash... when you have time, please rewrite your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
NSMutableArray *staffNamesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[userDefaults arrayForKey:@"staffNamesArray"]];
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: you shouldn't need 2 mutable copies

Comment: It's true, is copy and paste. Edit mi response

Comment: @Wain: *userDefaults* returns an immutable array, which I believe is the cause of the problem.  So, wouldn't weso's code make the userDefaults array mutable?

Comment: It was originally making a mutable copy and passing that to `initWithArray:`

Comment: @Wain I understand now... thanks for your help and I promise to do better when building my questions... :D