# Appending two arrays gives [__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, append

Hi I am using  below line of code,where both of my responseJson and indexpathArray are NSmutableArrays

```
[responseJson addObject:indexpathArray];
```

but I m getting

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

I have referred related topics [Getting "mutating method sent to immutable object" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710653/getting-mutating-method-sent-to-immutable-object-error?rq=1) but still the same

Actually here I am trying to append records from new array to old array where I am Getting 10 records every time from server.

Any help is appreciated!

**update**

```
    NSMutableArray *arrayResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:responseJson];
    // Now add objects top arrayResult
    [arrayResult addObject:finalarray];

    NSLog(@" arrayResult before :::  %@",arrayResult);

    responseJson = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arrayResult];//carshing here now
```

update:

```
 - (void)saveNearMeData:(id)response
 {
   NSArray *finalarray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   NSMutableArray = [response valueForKey:@"Deals"];
  indexpathArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:finalarray1];
   NSLog(@" finalarray before :::  %@",finalarray1);

    if(responseJson.count>0){

     NSMutableArray *arrayResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:responseJson];;

    // Now add objects top arrayResult
    [arrayResult addObject:finalarray];

    NSLog(@" arrayResult before :::  %@",arrayResult);
    responseJson = arrayResult;

  }else{
        responseJson = [response valueForKey:@"Deals"];
    }
  }
```

Comment: From the log,your `responseJson` is NSArray.

Comment: please provide your json data and array detail for getting some idea....

Comment: @Sujania Try like this [responseJson addObject:[indexpathArray mutableCopy]];

Comment: Try [[responseJson mutableCopy] addObject:indexpathArray];

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya that's the wrong way round, `responseJson` is immutable and needs to be mutable

Comment: @Wain yes you are right so what she want to do ?

Comment: `responseJson` is immutable.

Comment: @Darshan Kunjadiya still the same crash..responseJson Array in mutable array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please alloc your array at the time of assigning data while parsing. Hope that will resolve your crashing issue.

**Objective-C**

```
if ([arrayList count] == 0) {
                arrayList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[response valueForKey:@"Deals"]];
} else {
        [arrayList addObjectsFromArray:[response valueForKey:@"Deals"]];
}
```

**In Swift 3.0**

```
if arrayList.count == 0 {
     arrayList = response.value(forKey: "Deals") as! Array
} else {
     arrayList += response.value(forKey: "Deals") as! Array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the log it seems that `responseJson` is an NSArray and `addObject` is an NSMutableArray method.

You can do the following

```
NSMutableArray *arrayResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:responseJson];
// Now add objects top arrayResult
[arrayResult addObject:indexpathArray];
```

You are again trying to init the responseJson with the Given array. I think the responseJson is an `id`, so casting it might solve the problem. Please post the declaration of the responseJson or the method where it is obtained.
A safe bet would be to work with the `arrayResult` rather than the `responseJson` wherever you need it, and if you need it in any other method then please make `arrayResult` as an instance variable to obtain it globally.

Comment: @Sujania : that means `responseJson` was `NSArray` and not `NSMutableArray`

Comment: @Saheb Roy can you plz check my update once .. it is crashing. No it is an NSMutableArray

Comment: You still need to show what type of object is responseJson.. is it an `id`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use  addObjectsFromArray method  for example :

```
 NSArray *myArray = ...;
 NSMutableArray *bufferArray = [NSMutableArray new];
 [bufferArray addObjectsFromArray:myArray];
```

Comment: @RamaniAshish
Sorry, had a typo it should be :


[bufferArray addObjectsFromArray:myArray];

Answer (score 0):

Apply deep copy every time you get the response from the server because when you get the response from the server end, generally it is immutable.

Below line do the mutability on each level of responseJson.

```
NSMutableArray *responseJson = (NSMutableArray
*)CFBridgingRelease(CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFArrayRef)responseJson, kCFPropertyListMutableContainers));
```

You can also use the same line for NSMutableDictionary when you get the response in terms of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution:

I already have one array newsFeedListArry with objects & I am appending second array.

```
NSArray *arry = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"TEstig"];
[newsFeedListArry addObjectsFromArray:arry];
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is

```
NSMutableArray *test = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray : responseJson];
[test addObjectsFromArray : indexpathArray];
```

Comment: And for your kind attention I have used addObjectsFromArray instead so please comment after reading properly