# NSMutableArray of custom classes copy

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, copy, nsarray, deep-copy

I have an NSMutableArray of custom objects (based on NSObject) which I want to copy into a new array. But I want it to be a deep copy.

How do I go about doing this? Do I need to implement the NSCopying protocol in my custom object?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you need to indicate that your custom class adheres to the `NSCopying` protocol and then you implement the `copyWithZone:` method. This allows your class to be copied. In your implementation of `copyWithZone:` you need to decide how much of the internals also need deep copying.

Now if you do a deep copy of the array, the new array will include copied versions of your object and not just references to the originals.

Please note that a regular copy of an array doesn't do a deep copy. To make a deep copy you want something like:

```
NSArray *deepCopyArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:someArray copyItems:YES];
```

Comment: No, calling copy on an array will not make a deep copy, no matter what protocol the contained elements implement

Comment: @Eiko I never said calling `copy` on an array will make a deep copy. I stated how to ensure the custom object is copyable. I then mentioned that if a deep copy of the array is made...

Comment: @maddy Hmm ok, I think "Now if you do a deep copy of the array, ..." is easy to misunderstand, then.

Comment: So how does one go about deep copying? Is it part of these classes or does it need to be implemented in a category as I have seen on the web?

Comment: @Eiko Give me a minute to make a change before you edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I altered my code to create a new array from another (as in your example) rather than NSMutableArray *newArray = [oldarray copy]. I also implemented the NSCopying protocol in my own classes

Answer (score 1):

Deep copying an array can be done by going through all elements manually. This is necessary if the objects require further deep copying.

```
NSMutableArray *deepCopied = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[array count]];

// assumes your objects know how to "deepCopy"    
for (id object in array)
{
    // if not ARC or GC:
    [deepCopied addObject:[[object deepCopy] aurorelease]];

    // if ARC or GC
    [deepCopied addObject:[object deepCopy]];
}
```

Otherwise:

```
NSArray *deepCopied = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:array copyItems:YES];
```

There is a category method described in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453481/how-to-do-true-deep-copy-for-nsarray-and-nsdictionary-with-have-nested-arrays-di) that may help if you need to make a lot of deep copies.