# CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy doesn't work with keys as numbers

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I'm using `CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy` to make a deep mutable copy of an `NSDictionary`.  This example works fine.

```
NSDictionary *test = @{@"1": @"One"};
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = (__bridge NSMutableDictionary *)CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(NULL, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)test, kCFPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves);
```

This doesn't work when the `NSDictionary` uses an `NSNumber` for a key value.  `CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy` returns `nil`.  Here is an example.

```
NSDictionary *test = @{@(1): @"One"};
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = (__bridge NSMutableDictionary *)CFPropertyListCreateDeepCopy(NULL, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)test, kCFPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves);
```

How do I make a deep copy of an `NSDictionary` that has an `NSNumber` as a key value?

Comment: While it's fine to use any type of object for keys in an `NSDictionary`, property lists only support keys of type `NSString`.

Comment: You may wish to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453481/how-to-do-true-deep-copy-for-nsarray-and-nsdictionary-with-have-nested-arrays-di?s=3|0.4875 The 2nd answer is simple and clever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And although NSDictionary and CFDictionary objects allow their keys to be objects of any type, if the keys are not string objects, the collections are not property-list objects.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH3-54303

You cannot copy a property list with a non-string key, because this is no property list.

Simply iterate over the dictionary and copy the items manually.

```
@implemenatation NSDictionary (DeepCopy)
- (NSMutableDictionary*)deepMutableCopy
{
  NSMutableDictionary *copy = [NSMutableDictionary new];
  [self enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock
  ^(id key, id object)
  {
    if([object respondsToSelector:@selector(deepMutableCopy)])
    {
      object = [object deepMutableCopy];
    }
    else if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(mutableCopy)])
    {
      object = [object mutableCopy];
    }
    else if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(copy)]) // Maybe, maybe not
    {
      object = [object copy];
    }
    [copy setObject:object forKey:key]
  }];
  return copy;
}
```

Do the same with `NSArray`.

(For such tasks I would like to have components in Objective-C.)

Comment: It's not simple if the dictionary contains other collections. Clearly the example in the question is an overly simple example otherwise you can simply call `mutableCopy` on the original dictionary.

Comment: You need simple categories on `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`. I do not think that this is more than 20 lines of code. I add this to my answer.

Comment: Do the same with the other collection classes. Change `addObject:forKey:` to `setObject:forKey:` in the sample code.

Comment: Other? There are no other property list collections beside `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`!?